# Firebase not adding data to Realtime database in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was following along [this tutorial](https://cloudnweb.dev/2020/02/building-an-app-with-firebase-and-react-hooks-in-simple-way/) to connect Firebase using react hooks. I followed everything but I am having a problem interacting with the real-time database on my project. For example, when I tried to insert data into the database, it doesn't make any changes it just shows null; I tried to see if it was other problems, tried it with different accounts, creating new projects, but nothing seems to work.

My `App.js` looks like this:

```js
import React from "react"
import "./App.css"
import firebase from "./firebase"
function App() {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("notes")
        .add({
            title: "Working",
            body: "This is to check the Integration is working",
        });
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2>Note Taking App</h2>
            <p>using React Hooks and Firebase</p>
            <h3>Notes : </h3>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

I checked the rules for the realtime database on firebase, and it shows:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1610427600000",  // 2021-1-12
    ".write": "now < 1610427600000",  // 2021-1-12
  }
}
```

My app runs properly, but on the console, since I was logging the `XHRHttpRequests,` it shows something is failing on the `GET` request.

[image]

It is a newly created project and I only changed the `App.js` and added `firebase.js` that looks exactly like the one in the guide.

Comment: You have no code that checks the result of `add()` for errors.  It could be failing and you'd never know.  Also, the security rules you have here are for Realtime Database but your code is writing to Firestore.  They are completely different database systems.

Comment: Thank you I changed the `add()` to Realtime Database version and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security rules you show are for the Firebase Realtime Database, but the code you have is accessing Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and have different APIs.

To write to the Realtime Database would look something like this:

```
firebase
    .database()
    .ref("notes")
    .push({
        title: "Working",
        body: "This is to check the Integration is working",
    });
```

Comment: I tried to upvote but not enough reputation so I clicked on the checkmark (✓) to accept it